# Check if iterator to std::map points to second last element

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, stdmap, reverse-iterator

I'm (forward) iterating over a std::map and would like to find if the iterator points to the *second last* element.  I can't seem to find how to do that anywhere.

I've got:

```
bool
isSecondLastFile(const TDateFileInfoMap::const_iterator &tsFile)
{
    TDateFileInfoMap::reverse_iterator secondLastIt = mFileInfoMap.rbegin()  + 1;
    return (tsFile == secondLastIt);
}
```

Where `TDateFileInfoMap` is std::map

I'm getting:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘tsFile == secondLastIt’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:287: note: candidates are: bool std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>&) const [with _Tp = std::pair<const long int, TFileInfo>]
```

Does that mean I can't compare the forward and reverse iterator?

How do I figure out if the forward iterator is pointing at the second last element?

Comment: How about `tsFile + 2 == mFileInfoMap.end()`?

Answer (score 6):

[`std::map`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) iterator type is [`BidirectionalIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). Just decrement the `end` iterator twice--first to get the last element since `m.end()` returns an iterator at the after the end position, and then again to get the second-last element:

```
auto penultimate = std::prev(m.end(), 2);
```

Then you can simply check for equality with the resultant iterator:

```
auto it = m.begin();
it == penultimate;
```

[see it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c969ee0f606ff146)

Naturally, you should check that the map *has* two elements first if it's not guaranteed by other logic in your program.

Comment: Consecutive `operator--` are hardly readable. Why not use `auto back = std::prev(m.end(), 2)`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault because it hadn't occurred to me. Thanks, and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean I can't compare the forward and reverse iterator?

Yes you can't compare them directly.

You can use [`base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) to get the underlying base iterator.

> Returns the underlying base iterator. That is
>   `std::reverse_iterator(it).base() == it`.
>
> The base iterator refers to the element that is next (from the
>   `std::reverse_iterator::iterator_type` perspective) to the element the
>   `reverse_iterator` is currently pointing to. That is `&*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit`.

e.g.

```
return (tsFile == (++secondLastIt).base());
```

BTW: `mFileInfoMap.rbegin() + 1` won't compile since the iterator of `std::map` is not [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). You might write:

```
TDateFileInfoMap::reverse_iterator secondLastIt = mFileInfoMap.rbegin();
++secondLastIt;
```

---

<sup>Note that we're not checking whether the map is empty or has only one element.</sup>

Comment: Doing this seems to return the last element, not second last.  But looking at the definition of base() I'm not sure why that is...

Comment: @Danny [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)'s the explanations about reverse iterator.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for forward iterators:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
inline bool isNthLast(std::size_t n, ForwardIterator pos, ForwardIterator last) {
    for( ;; --n, ++pos) {
        if(n == 0) 
            return (pos == last);
        if(pos == last)
            return false;
    }
}

bool isSecondLastFile(TDateFileInfoMap::const_iterator sFile) {
    return isNthLast(2, sFile, mFileInfoMap.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a set with name s.

s= {s1,s2,...,sN-1, sN}
Now to iterate from s1.. to sN-1 (which is second last element) we will use STL functions, s.begin() and s.end().

end = s.end(); //end  points to end

end--// end points to sN

Now in the for loop when itr (starts from the beginning of set) becomes equal to sN the loop will break, and you will get s1,s2,..sN-1 inside the loop.

```
map<int,int> s;

// to iterate till fixed range in map

auto end =s.end();
end--; // end to second last;

for(auto itr = s.begin(); itr!=end;itr++){
  // do your operation
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation on how this code solve the problem